# How to send OpenCV video footage over ZeroMQ sockets?

Tags: python, opencv, video, streaming, zeromq

I've got a simple webcam which I read out using OpenCV and I'm now trying to send this video footage to a different (Python) program using [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). So I've got the following simple script to read out the webcam and send it using a ZeroMQ socket:

```
import cv2
import os
import zmq
import base64

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

# init the camera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    try:
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()            # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))       # resize the frame
        footage_socket.send_string(base64.b64encode(frame))

        # Show the video in a window
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)                  # show the frame to our screen
        cv2.waitKey(1)                              # Display it at least one ms
        #                                           # before going to the next frame

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print "\n\nBye bye\n"
        break
```

This works well in that it shows the video and doesn't give any errors.

I commented out the two lines which show the image (`cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.waitKey(1)`). I then started the script below in paralel. This second script should receive the video footage and show it.

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, unicode(''))

# camera = cv2.VideoCapture("output.avi")

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
        frame = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(frame), dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)                  # show the frame to our screen
        cv2.waitKey(1)                              # Display it at least one ms
        #                                           # before going to the next frame
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

print "\n\nBye bye\n"
```

Unfortunately, this freezes on `cv2.waitKey(1)`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Do I need to decode the footage differently? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by taking intermediate steps. I first wrote individual images to disk, and then I read out those images again. That led me to the fact that I needed to encode the frame as an image (I opted for jpg), and with the magic methods `cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)` and `cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)` I could make it work. I pasted the full working code below.

This first script reads out the webcam and sends the footage over a zeromq socket:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

while True:
    try:
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        footage_socket.send_string(base64.b64encode(buffer))
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print "\n\nBye bye\n"
        break
```

and this second script receives the frame images and displays them:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, unicode(''))

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
        img = base64.b64decode(frame)
        npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
        cv2.imshow("image", source)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print "\n\nBye bye\n"
        break
```

Answer (score 8):

### Step 0: Inventory of Risks

Given the target is clear, your rapid-prototyping of the distributed application infrastructure depends on several risky points.

**0)** OpenCV **`cv2`** module heavily uses underlying C-based components and python beauty hangs quite often if trying to use `cv2.imshow()` facilities and `cv2` ( external FSA ) window-management & frame-display services.

**1)** ZeroMQ framework can help you a lot more than to try to enforce data to be cast into `(string)` just to use `.send_string() / .recv_string()` - may get better here once rather moving the known image `( pxW * pxH )`geometry * RGB-depth inside some smarter BLOB-mapped object ( will speak about this aspect a bit more in architecture outlook below ).

**2)** Given points 0 & 1, the ZeroMQ infrastructure ( the more in prototyping ) ought become robust against unhandled exceptions ( which would leave `zmq.Context()` instances & their associated `.Socket()` children hanging on their own on allocated resources in case `cv2.imshow()` crashes, as it quite often does so in rapid prototyping loops.

Thus a thoroughful & self-disciplined framing of the code inside a **`try: except: finally:`** handler & explicit initial **`.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )`** immediately upon socket instantiation + final **`.close()`** + **`context.term()`** inside the `finally:` handler section are a fair must.

---

### Step 1: Validate the ZeroMQ part by sending a `SEQ` of plain `int`-s

The best first level of problem isolation is to setup the flow, just to deliver an uncontrolled `SEQ` of integers, being `.send( )` broadcast from **`PUB`** side.

```
...                                                   # FOR STREAMING, ALWAYS PREFER DESIGNS USING A NONBLOCKING MODE
SEQ += 1
footage_socket.send( SEQ, zmq.NOBLOCK )               # PUB.send( SEQ ) -> *SUB*
...
```

Unless your receiving side demonstrates it's robust handling of a flow of int-s, it makes no sense to proceed any further.

```
...
aMsgIN = footage_socket.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )           # FOR STREAMING, ALWAYS PREFER DESIGNS USING A NONBLOCKING MODE
print "{0:}".format( aMsgIN if len( aMsgIN ) > 0 else "." ),
# sleep(...)                                          # backthrottle the loop a bit
...
```

---

### Step 2: Decouple `.imshow()` from `.recv()` data & event-loops

In case your data-pumps work as needed, the remote display starts to make sense as a next target.

ZeroMQ delivers either a complete message ( a BLOB ), or nothing. This is a fact. Next, ZeroMQ does not warrant anyone to deliver error-free. These are the facts, your design has to live with.

The acquisition is the simpler part, just grab the data ( maybe some colourspace conversions may take centrally here, but otherwise, the task is ( for sub 4K / sub 30fps image processing ) typically error-free on this side.

**`frame`**, as acquired above, is a **`numpy.ndarray`** instance. The best performance would be received on sending a hard-coded, binary-mapped BLOB, without any "smart" conversions, as obviously, the `frame` is just a big pack of bits ( though there are some more advanced delicacies possible with Zero-copy mechanics of ZeroMQ, but these would make no direct benefit in this stage on the sender side ).

```
#                               struct.unpack() / .pack() seems "just"-enough for fast & smart custom Payload protocol designs
DecodeWireMSG_DATA( aMSG_DATA = struct.unpack( "!" + ( aPayloadHEADER + ( ( pxW * pxH ) * RGB_DEPTH * CELL_SIZE ) ) * "I", aMsgIN ) )
```

The harder part is on the receiver side. If one tries to use the `cv2` built-in event-loop engine, hidden inside `.imshow()`, this loop will collide with your external logic of reading a flow of updates via `.recv()` as published from the `PUB` side.

As a reasonable compromise, one may ignore all the "delayed" `frame`-s, that did not get processes in sync with the `PUB`-side acquisition / broadcast cadency, and just display the most recent one ... using **`zmq.CONFLATE`** option on the ZeroMQ transport infrastructure ( delayed "old" pictures have lost their sense if the purpose of the reconstruction of the flow-of-events is just a visual preception, on the contrary, if the purpose is to document the complete acquisition 1:1, the `zmq.CONFLATE` would be discarding `frame` instances, which ought get processed, so some other architecture ought be added for such a 1:1 documentographic purpose, best separate from the "just-visual" branch of the flow of data / processing ).

Having done this, the `.recv()` ( might be a composition of a `Poller()` + `.recv()` loop ) will provide the `SUB` side an appropriate data-pump, that is independent from the `cv2` tools and it's `.imshow()` ( hidden )-FSA event-loop.

---

### Architecture & Performance Hints:

- for higher fps + FullHD / 2K / 4K projects, profile systematically the accumulated processing latencies / delays of the `cv2` processing, using zmq.Stopwatch() instances' `{ .start(), .stop() }` methods.
- having hard data, you may in time detect, when additional needs appear to solve some even harder-real-time constraints, so think about:
- principally avoid any risk of falling into any uncontrollable black-hole of python garbage collection -- **always control** `{ gc.disable() | gc.enable();gc.collect() }` surrounding your critical-path sections and launching an explicit `gc.collect()` where your design knows it is feasible.
- avoid new memory allocation delays -- may **pre-allocate** all necessary  `numpy` arrays and later just enforce `numpy` to use for those an inplace mode of data modifications, thus avoiding any further ad-hoc memory management associated wait-states
- design the traffic for increased error-immunity with separate, multi-streamed, independent updates of just sections ( stripes ) of the whole large / (colour)-deep image ( remember Zero-Warranty - getting either a complete "fat"-message or **`None`** )
- tune-up the **`.Context()`**'s performance using **`zmq.AFFINITY`** to map different classes of I/O traffic priorities onto segregated `zmq.Context( N )` I/O-threads.
- fine-tune **`zmq.SNDBUF`** + **`zmq.SNDHWM`** on PUB side, if multi-subscribers are expected and **`zmq.CONFLATE`** is not used.
- last but not least, may harness **`numba.jit()`** LLVM-pre-compiled acceleration of re-useable code for the critical-path functions ( typically the heavy `numpy` processing ), where additional microseconds shaved-off bring their most beneficial effects on your video-processing pipeline, while still remaining in the comfort of pure python ( well, sure, still with some `cv2` caveats ).

---

### Some more hints & tricks with `cv2` in prototyping phase:

May like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153611) for `cv2` based image-processing.

May like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563388) for `cv2` simple GUI-interactive parameter tuning of methods.

May like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37395550) for `cv2` processing pipeline profiling with **`zmq.Stopwatch()`** details down to `[usec]`

Answer (score 1):

The frame object contains memory states for the server state and when it's sent to the client it freezes because the frame it receives is a shallow copy.
Try looking up how you can make a deep copy for the frame.